# Why are my entities no longer capable of collision when added as children of AnchorEntities?

Tags: realitykit, visionos

I have a wall entity, which is just a plane, and a wall anchor.

If I manually place the wall entity somewhere in my space, I can bounce a ball off of it.

But if I add it as a child of the anchor entity, then the ball goes through the wall. Why is this?

```
@State var wall: Entity = {
        let mesh = MeshResource.generatePlane(width: wallCanvasSize.x,
                                              depth: wallCanvasSize.y)
        let wall = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh,
                               materials: [SimpleMaterial(color: .blue.withAlphaComponent(0.1), isMetallic: false)])
        wall.name = "wall"
        
        wall.components.set(InputTargetComponent())
        
        wall.components.set(PhysicsBodyComponent(mode: .static))
        
        wall.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
        
        wall.components.set(CollisionComponent(shapes: [.generateBox(width: wallCanvasSize.x,
                                                                     height: wallCanvasSize.x,
                                                                     depth: wallCanvasSize.y)]))

       return wall
    }()
    
    @State var wallAnchor: AnchorEntity = {
        let anchor = AnchorEntity(.plane(.vertical,
                                         classification: .wall,
                                         minimumBounds: wallCanvasSize))
        anchor.components.set(PhysicsBodyComponent(mode: .static))
        
        anchor.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
        
        anchor.components.set(CollisionComponent(shapes: [.generateBox(width: wallCanvasSize.x,
                                                                     height: wallCanvasSize.x,
                                                                     depth: wallCanvasSize.y)]))

        anchor.name = "wallAnchor"
        
        return anchor
    }()
```

Comment: Have you tried without adding collision (and physics) to the anchor?